# Installing snakemake without internet

Tags: installation, snakemake

I am working on a station where internet communication is forbidden. Is it possible to install snakemake without conda?

Thanks,
Michelle

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be installed via pip as well. However, that still needs a download. With conda, you should also be able to download the package and all dependencies via anaconda.org, and then copy it over to that machine. But it certainly will require some manual steps. There is also a docker container. This is probably easier, because it is only a single file.